# What is the difference between「下げる」 and 「下ろす」?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I know both involve lowering something from a higher position to a lower one, but what is the difference in connotation? I know that when おろす is written as 降ろす it has some other meanings, but when represented as 下ろす, what separates it from 下げる?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both 下ろす and 下げる means to physically lowering something, but when you use 下ろす, the target object is typically **already elevated or on top of something**, and it will be usually moved to the completely un-elevated position.

- 旗を下ろす ("to take down the flag (completely)")
- 腰を下ろす ("to sit down")
- 手を下ろす ("to lower one's (raised) hand")
- 銃口を下ろす
- 荷物を車から下ろす
- 屋根に積もった雪を下ろす
- バスの乗客を全員下ろす

下げる tends to be chosen when lowering something from its normal/original position.

- 旗を下げる (can also mean adjusting the position while the flag is still raised)
- 腰を下げる ("to lower your hip position", "to half-squat")
- 頭を下げる ("to bow")
- 壁のポスターの位置を少し下げる

---

And both 下ろす and 下げる have many derivative and/or non-physical meanings, which you have to remember one-by-one. I won't go into detail, but important ones include:

下ろす

- to withdraw (money)
- to grate (food)
- to remove (someone from a position); to relegate

下げる

- to lower (a setting, a price, temperature, etc)
- to carry (a bag), to wear (a necklace)
- to take away (a finished plate/document/etc)

Answer (score 0):

下げる is to lower, and it acts in contrast to 上げる, which means to raise.

手を上げる raise one's hand

vs

手を下げる lower one's hand

下ろす is not so much to "lower" as it is to "bring/take down," "unload" or "discharge," and acts in contrast to 下りる.

In this sense, it acts as a transitive verb, in contrast to 下りる which is intransitive.

幕が下りる curtain comes down

vs.

幕を下ろす curtain is brought down/pulled down/caused to come down